# Django data problem : new salons always with all users

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, localhost

Problem is that I want to create a new salon, so beginning with only the user who created it.
But, when I consult my django database (with localhost:8000/admin/), I notice that every user (UserSalon) is present in every 'Salon'...
However, when I print all the users of this salon in the terminal, I can see there is only this one.
So wtf?

I have this in my models.py:

```
class UserSalon(models.Model):
    # etc.
    
class Salon(models.Model):
    salon_users = models.ManyToManyField(UserSalon)
    # etc.
```

and this is a part of code from my view.py:

```
        user_salon_id = request.session.get('user_salon_id')

    if request.method == 'POST':
        create_salon_form = CreateSalonForm(request.POST)

        try:
            user_salon = UserSalon.objects.get(id=user_salon_id)
        except UserSalon.DoesNotExist:
            user_salon = None 

        if create_salon_form.is_valid():
            created_id_salon = create_salon_form.cleaned_data['id_salon']
            created_key_salon = create_salon_form.cleaned_data['key_salon']   
            
            new_salon = Salon.objects.create(id_salon=created_id_salon, key_salon=created_key_salon)
            new_salon.salon_users.clear()

            new_salon.salon_users.add(user_salon) 
            new_salon.save()
```

(What I see in field 'user' from table 'UserSalon' :
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VjEp4.png))

Comment: When you say  "I notice that every user (UserSalon) is present in every 'Salon'..." does that mean that you see them in the UserSalon box of every Salon?  I think the admin is just showing you all the UserSalon objects available to select.  The dark ones are the ones that are actually connected to the Salon object in question.  Perhaps a screenshot of what you are seeing would help.

Comment: @raphael I don't think that's it because it just shows every user, all in the same color. I've added a picture below the code.

Comment: That *is* how they will appear in the admin for a ManyToManyField when they are *not* associated.  I see 141 UserSalon objects in your image.  You stated that "when I print all the users of this salon in the terminal, I can see there is only this one".  Look for that UserSalon in that list.  It should be darker (it is selected, and associated with the Salon).

Comment: Or, try to select multiple UserSalon objects from the list (using the ctrl key to select multiple ones).  Save it in the admin panel.  Then try printing, and you should see the ones you selected printed out in the terminal.

Comment: @raphael I just noticed you are right. Itis true that in Salon12, I have the 12th object UserSalon in dark in the list, even if all users are in that list.
I also tried printing all users of the last created session, thats shows only one.
So now, my question is : Is it possible not to show every users in every table ? I need a clear view for when I'd add users in a salon and other ones.

Comment: I don't know @Noam.  It is a good question.  The admin panel has to show them all, since there has to be a way for you to be able to select the UserSalon objects you want associated with the Salon.  Personally, I rarely use the admin panel.  Instead, I just write a view with a form that handles the same thing, but in a format I like.  For example, I use a JavaScript function (https://tarekraafat.github.io/autoComplete.js/#/) to create a more manageable search box that does not show everything, but shows ones that match what you type, as you type.

Comment: I will try that, thank you @raphael !